# Checking if there are any related entries

Tags: ee2, templates, relationships

I'm building what I imagine to be a fairly stock-standard page template on a very standard EE setup.

I'm attempting to use EE 2.6.1's new native Relationships field type to link articles to each other, and to pages from another channel.

What I need to do is check if there are any related articles for the current page/article *before* I spit out the related content (if it's there). This is mainly so I can show or hide the "Related Articles" as appropriate.

My basic code looks like this:

```
{if related_articles}
    <h3>Related Articles</h4>
    {related_articles}
        {related_articles:title} (etc...)
    {/related_articles}
{if:else}
    There are no related articles.
{/if}
```

This just returns the message about there being no related articles.

However, if I take the `{related_articles}` loop out of the conditional, it performs exactly as expected.

This type of check would work just fine with any other type of channel field variable, so I'm a little confused as to why it's not working here.

I've checked over the official [Relationships documentation](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html) a couple of times, but it doesn't seem to mention this type of scenario.

Am I doing something wrong, or missing something obvious? Is this something that can be achieved with EE's new native relationships?

**Update:**
Ok, shortly after posting this I found [this question](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13028/relationship-what-im-doing-wrong), the answer to which helped me out.

I find the solution to be a little messy (nesting my title and any opening and closing DIVs within the loop itself - potentially necessitating multiple conditionals within the loop) but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That won't work as the relationship is a tag pair, so at it's basic you could use:

```
{if "{related_articles}{related_articles:title}{/related_articles}"}
    <h3>Related Articles</h4>
    {related_articles}
        {related_articles:title} (etc...)
    {/related_articles}
{if:else}
    There are no related articles.
{/if}
```

But that's really clunky.

The documentation isn't great, but reading the comments from the [docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html), Hop Studios has the solution:

```
 {parents field="my_field"}
   {if parents:no_results}NOTHING FOUND{/if}
   (<a href="{comment_url_title_auto_path}">{parents:title}</a> {count} {parents:count})
 {/parents}
```

So at a guess, try this:

```
{related_articles}
    {if no_results}
        There are no related articles.
    {/if}
    {if count == 1}<h3>Related Articles</h3>{/if}

    {related_articles:title} (etc...)
{/related_articles}
```

This **may** also work...

```
{if related_articles:no_results}
    ...
{if:else}
    ...
{/if}
```

FYI: Your original... `<h3>Related Articles</h4>`

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your response!

I actually like your "clunky" idea better than what I've ended up with (see the link in my update). I find nesting conditionals that will only ever return true once (for example, `if count==1`) within loops to be far clunkier, if for no other reason than it has to cause a performance hit (however negligible).

Comment: Actually, I ust tried your final solution (`if related_articles:no_results`) and it worked beautifully! Seems that's a pretty ideal way to run it, just requires turning my mental processes around a bit. Thanks!

Comment: Another followup: that solution generates a parse error if the conditional returns true; that is if I'm on a page that *doesn't* have any related articles. Guess I'm going back to running the conditional check within the loop.

Comment: Doh!  My else was wrong, not sure if you modified that in your code. Also you may be able to wrap it in quotes - {if "{related_articles:no_results}"}